# Users of an application on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I have seen some applications that display on a map the users who have the application in use or installed.

I'd like to implement something like this in my project, the problem is I do not know where to start ..

anyone know any reference I can read?

This is an image to try to explain what I want

[image]

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When user installs app, get its location using GPS, send it to your Server save it there.
2. When you want to show map, get all locations saved on server and display it on map.

You can update user location each time application is launched, updated it on server as well.